# JavaScript Image Hide

Tags: javascript, image, hide

I am making a game in javascript and I needed help with the following:

I want to make an image = to a variable then I only want to show the image when I want it too.

So I want the image by default hidden but it is always showing whatever I do. I am only a beginner and I have looked at this page and others on the internet to help me: http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascriptexamples/javascript-hide-image.shtml

This is the code so far:

```
<html> <head></head>
<body>
     <img src="http://wwcdn.weddingwire.com/static/vendor/55001_60000/56375/thumbnails/64x‌​64_SQ_1342622451725-Matangiaerial.jpg"
          id="islandimg">
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var playermoney = 10000;
     var islandarray = new array;
     var car = 500; var watch = 100;
     var diamond = 2000;
     function hideImage() { 
          if (document.getElementById) {
               document.getElementById('islandimg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
     </script>
</body></html>
```

The code has other stuff in it for the game but ignore it.

Comment: Please add the code to the question by editing it.

Comment: I have been trying for 45 mins now I still cant do it I have been looking at different articles still cant do it plz help?

Comment: You have a function called hideImage but you're never calling it.

Comment: Do you even execute the hideImage function? (`hideImage()`)

Comment: the image returns 404...

Comment: @j08691 w/r/t your edit: is there a moderation guideline to remove signatures from questions?

Comment: @Kos- Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: @JoshNaro `/>` is syntax of XML and XHTML; HTML allows XML-like end tags but doesn't require them. @j08691 thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and do this:

```
function hideImage() {
  $('#islandimg').hide();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

An other option would be this:

```
function hideImage() { 
    document.getElementById('islandimg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

or this:

```
function hideImage() { 
    document.getElementById('islandimg').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Whats the difference between the last two => http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm

It seams you want to toggle the visible state of the image so you should create a `show` function too. (By using jQuery you can use the `toggle()` function for that.)

If you don't want to display the image you could also hide it with `CSS` by default and then toggle the display state with `JavaScript` with your `showImage()` function.

```
#islandimg {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
#islandimg {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Sure, let's load all of jQuery to hide an image.

Comment: True but not helpful. You could also use a hundred other helper libraries but none are actually needed for this task

Comment: I thought when he is developing a game this will not be the only js function and with a helper lib like jQuery he maybe can write code that is better readable.

Comment: If he's making a game like he says, jQuery will probably be very useful for DOM manipulation.

Comment: So would a thousand other libraries. The answer to a **JavaScript** question is not "use jQuery". Adding such a massive dependency makes this a particularly bad answer to the question as it was asked.

Comment: Ok, I added an update with some more solutions to solve this problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reasons this doesn't work

1. The Image returns 404
2. As other stated, `array` is undefined
3. Missing ending `}` after the if statement

Here is a working version in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6dgN/)

Here is the JS part with comments

```
 var playermoney = 10000;
 var islandarray = new Array(); //array was undefined. 
 // a more concise way to write this by the way is: var islandarray = [];
 var car = 500; var watch = 100;
 var diamond = 2000;
 function hideImage() { 
      if (document.getElementById) {
           document.getElementById('islandimg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
 }//Missing end braces 

 hideImage(); //missing call to the function
```

By the way, the easiest way to find out of these issues is to look at Chrome / Firefox console, it will complain on things like the `array` variable issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like syntax errors on your page ..

```
var islandarray = new array;
```

supposed to be

`var islandarray = new Array();`  **OR**  `var islandarray = [] ;`

Also you never seem to **calling the function** . you are just **declaring it** ..

```
hideImage(); // Call this function in your script 
             //  after taking care of the errors.. 

function hideImage() { 
          if (document.getElementById) {
               document.getElementById('islandimg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
};  -- > Missing this as well

hideImage();  // Then call your function
```

**[check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snDme/)**

Comment: Could just as well be simply `var islandarray = [];`

Comment: And also there is a missing ending `}` for the if statememt

Answer (score 1):

As a few comments (mine included) are suggesting, you're never actually calling the function.  Here's my edit to your script

```
<html> <head></head>
<body>
     <img src="http://wwcdn.weddingwire.com/static/vendor/55001_60000/56375/thumbnails/64x‌64_SQ_1342622451725-Matangiaerial.jpg"
          id="islandimg">
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var playermoney = 10000;
     var islandarray = new Array();
     var car = 500; var watch = 100;
     var diamond = 2000;
     function hideImage() {
          if (document.getElementById) {
               document.getElementById('islandimg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
         }
// NOW CALL hideImage() TO MAKE IT DO SOMETHING
hideImage();
     </script>
</body></html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rVnfF/

Comment: Don't forget the closing brace :)

Comment: two issues from original post. 1) `new Array();` not `new array;` and 2) called `hideImage()`

Comment: You Guys Are The Best. I May Not Be Great At Coding But U Are All Great At Helping. Thanks Everyone For Helping Out!

Comment: Hi, I was just going to ask if you could help me again. I want the array Island to have the variable of how much it is worth (7,000) and and another var which is the image so later on in the code whenever I wanted to get rid of this item I could. Could you help me with this?

Comment: if anyone else could help it would be great

Answer (score 0):

The provious posts already answer your question.
If you want to call the function where the page loads you need to insert this code:

```
<body onload="hideImage();">
```

but correct the other errors:

```
var islandarray = new Array();
```

and the final }

otherwise jscript will no load. 
You should use Firefox with Firebug (or other tools) to check for errors!